# CAShapeLayer disappears while moving

Tags: swift, macos, layer

CAShapeLayer disappears while moving to another monitor, but not always

Tried searching for code examples

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)
{
    //super.draw(dirtyRect)
    image?.lockFocus()
    print("SelectionRect::draw")
    if (shapeLayerIsVisible) {
        auxLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }

    //let origin = frame.origin
    auxLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    auxLayer.strokeColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
    auxLayer.fillColor = nil
    auxLayer.lineWidth = 1.0

    //rectSize = CGSize(width: x2 - x1, height: y2 - y1)
    let selectionRect = frame //CGRect(x: origin.x, y: origin.y, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
    let auxPath = CGMutablePath()
    //print("x1: \(x1), y1: \(y1), x2: \(x2), y2: \(y2), width: \(rectSize.width), height: \(rectSize.height)")

    auxPath.addRect(selectionRect)
    auxLayer.path = auxPath
    layer?.addSublayer(auxLayer)

    shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [5, 5]

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addRect(selectionRect)
    shapeLayer.path = path

    let lineDashAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "lineDashPhase")
    lineDashAnimation.fromValue = 0
    lineDashAnimation.toValue = shapeLayer.lineDashPattern?.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.intValue }
    lineDashAnimation.duration = 1
    lineDashAnimation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    shapeLayer.add(lineDashAnimation, forKey: nil)

    shapeLayerIsVisible = true

    layer?.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

I've got an 5K iMac with two external 4K monitors (all three scaled to look like 2560x1440 if that matters). With the given code, the NSView is initialized with x: 0, y:0, width: 100, height: 100. All works well, I can drag the Windows around on all three monitors. When I moved the Layer with the mouse to a different position and than drag the window to a different monitor the Shape disappears.

Edit: I fixed it by calling draw(9 at the end of each mouseDragged()-Event and chaninging selectionRect from frame to bounds. It works, but is that a clean solution?

Comment: Don't call `draw` directly (see the Apple docs), instead to invalidate a view, use `setNeedsDisplay`

Comment: thx @Koen, that still works, feels more like the right thing to do.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If the answer below solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I don't see a checkmark to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Ah yes, you need a minimum of 15 reputation points to be able to accept an answer, see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `draw()` yourself, per Apple's documentation:

> You should never call draw() directly yourself. To invalidate part of your view, and thus cause that portion to be redrawn, call the setNeedsDisplay() or setNeedsDisplay(_:) method instead.